# Why Pointers in 64 bit architect are able to point addresses which aren't exist at all?

Tags: pointers

A pointer in 64 bit architect takes 64 bits in memory. For every different value of the pointer points another byte, that means it can point one of different 2^64 addresses of bytes .

2^64 bytes = 2^54 kb = 2^44 mb = 2^34 gb = 2^24 Tb = 16777216 Tb

but none of rams even hard drives has such a big space.

So Why is it it? Couldn't pointers have been smaller? Or am I wrong?

Comment: A lot of computer operations work best on numbers that are powers of 2- 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ... And that is certainly the case for memory sizes.  64 bit is the next power up after 32 bit, just as 32-bit followed after 16-bit.

Comment: Look up canonical pointers on x86-64. Then note that the number of actually-used bits has been extended at least once as memories have gotten larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure they could be smaller...
basically if you have individually addressable bytes... then the whole RAM space needs to fit inside of the pointer address space.

so 32 bit supported up to 4GiB or 2GiB if there is a flag bit of some sort...
that isn't enough now for modern computing... the next size up could be [33](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZEBRA_(computer)), or [34](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Universal_Digital_Computer_M-2), or [48](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/FSQ-32)... but 64-bit is now the native width... and no number greater than 32 divides into 64 more than once... so 64-bit (or 63 if you want one flag bit of some sort) makes pretty good sense